# BeautifulSoup won't get the page source using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a webpage but I can't get the html text of the website using selenium.

here is my code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse

search_term = raw_input("What is your search term?: ")
url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q="
googurl = url+search_term
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

htmltext = driver.get(googurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext.page_source)
```

doing this I get the traceback

```
What is your search term?: hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google page click.py", line 15, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext.page_source)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'page_source'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to always use the driver object:

```
driver.get(googurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```